# Set root to current drive in GRUB

Tags: grub2

GRUB require one to set the root drive in its config. Usually one write something like `search --set=root /boot/vmlinuz` or explicitly `set root=(hd0,1)`. I found this little excessive considering the fact that GRUB already know the drive it loads config from. How can I force grub to set root to the drive he used to read config from?

Answer (score 1):

That is what it defaults to; explicitly setting it just gives the ability to change it to another drive.  It is useful if your root partition is different ( different partition on the same disk, or another disk ) than your /boot partition.

Comment: From the manual: "The default is normally set by GRUB at startup based on the value of ‘prefix’" and "'prefix' is normally set by GRUB at startup based on information provided by grub-install" so it is basically hardcoded in stage 1.5 and will become wrong if you change the order of discs or partitions

Comment: @ZAB, there is no stage 1.5 ( or 1 or 2 ) in grub2; those are legacy grub things.

Comment: Its only a semantic. The problem that it is hardcoded there during an install phase.

Comment: @ZAB It's not as hardcoded as you think. Look in `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/grub.cfg` on an EFI system and you'll see this is where root and prefix are set. For MBR you'll find an embedded config at the end of the image that is written to the MBR or GRUB bios boot partition.